# How to get comment's field value in view

Tags: views

I want to create rating of companies based on values of comments fields.

**Companies rate table:**
[image]

**Comment form example:**
[image]

Here's my Drupal settings:

Nodes (type "Company") with comments.
Comments with additional fields (as taxonomy vocabularies): stability, support, performance. My vocabularies list:
[image: taxonomy vocab]

For example, vocabulary "Performance" has terms:
[image]

Also, I added additional field "points" (integer) in this vocabulary:
[image]

Term edit page:
[image]

I want a View to display sum of values of comments fields. The problem is that view doesn't allow to get comment fields integer values.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Can you edit your question and reduce it to a specific question with the related info in it? In this case it seems to be about setting up a view that fetches integer fields from comments.